# Windsor Castle 3.0 use IContributeComponentModelConstruction to set lifestyle to WcfPerOperation

Tags: wcf, castle-windsor, windsor-3.0, windsor-facilities

In Windsor 2.1, I have the following piece of code to change lifestyle of all services to PerWcfOperation when the code is executed in wcf context:

```
    container.Kernel.ComponentModelBuilder.AddContributor(
            new CustomLifestyleLevelingContributeComponentModelConstruction(typeof (PerWcfOperationLifestyle))
```

where CustomLifestyleLevelingContributeComponentModelConstruction is:

```
public class CustomLifestyleLevelingContributeComponentModelConstruction : IContributeComponentModelConstruction
{
    private readonly Type customLifestyleType;
    private readonly List<LifestyleType> ignoredLifetyles;

public CustomLifestyleLevelingContributeComponentModelConstruction(Type customLifestyleType)
    {
        this.customLifestyleType = customLifestyleType;
    }
    public void ProcessModel(IKernel kernel, ComponentModel model)
    {
        model.LifestyleType = LifestyleType.Custom;
        model.CustomLifestyle = customLifestyleType;
    }
}
```

My problem is that the *class* PerWcfOperationLifestyle has been removed from Windsor 3.0. Could anyone please show me how I can achieve the same goal with Windsor 3.x?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?  I'm trying to do the same thing.

Comment: Yes, I just added an answer for those who need to do the same thing :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem by rewriting the ProcessModel method as the below:

```
public void ProcessModel(IKernel kernel, ComponentModel model)
    {
            model.LifestyleType = LifestyleType.Scoped;
            model.ExtendedProperties[Constants.ScopeAccessorType] = typeof(WcfOperationScopeAccessor);
    }
```